# Implementing a search bar in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, filter, appbar

I am implementing a forum application and i would like to include a search bar to filter out posts based on its title. Tutorials that i've seen have hard-coded strings stored in a list and filtering is done from this list. However, i have to filter based on the title of the posts available in the forum which are stored in a class 'Post' and the stream of posts is fetched from firebase. How do i extract the title out from the posts without the hard-coding?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very general question, but I will do my best to give a general rundown. Let's say your `Post` class as the following api:

```
class Post {
  String name;
}
```

and you have a list of posts named `_allPosts` set to all of the posts from Firebase and another empty list named `posts`. Every time your search field's `onChanged` trigger is called you could call the following function:

```
void filterSearchResults(String query) {
    List<Post> searchMatches = List<Post>();
    searchMatches.addAll(_allPosts);
    if (query.isNotEmpty) {
      List<Post> dummyListData = List<Post>();
      searchMatches.forEach((item) {
        if (item.name.toString().toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())) {
          dummyListData.add(item);
        }
      });
      posts = dummyListData;
    } else {
      posts= _originalPlayers;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

The `notifyListeners` is if you are using Provider, if not you could just wrap your function in `setState()`.